# How to save a list as a CSV file with new lines?

Tags: python, pandas, list, csv

I would like to save a Python list in a CSV file, for example I have a list like this:

```py
['hello','how','are','you']
```

I would like to save it as:

```
colummn,
hello,
how,
are,
you,
```

I tried the following:

```py
myfile = open('/Users/user/Projects/list.csv', 'wb')
wr = csv.writer(myfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL,'\n')
wr.writerow(pos_score)
```

Comment: `for score in pos_score: wr.writerow([score])`

Comment: just iterate through the list and write row to csv each time

`for i,it in enumerate(list):` `wr.writerow([it])`

Answer (score 88, accepted):

use pandas `to_csv` (http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(some_list, columns=["colummn"])
>>> df.to_csv('list.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. How can I add a `,` at the end of each word?. Do you think I'll have problems to read this kind of list since with pandas since is a .csv?

Comment: Nope, pandas deal well with csv. Just use its method read_csv.

if you realy need ',' at the end of line, run:
df['colummn'] = df['colummn'].map(lambda x: x+",")

However csv format does not suppose file to have ',' at the end of line, only in between columns. Adding ',' after words would mean that there is a second column (what is not true in your case).

Answer (score 17):

If you want all the words on different lines you need to set the deliiter to `\n`:

```
l = ['hello','how','are','you']
import  csv

with open("out.csv","w") as f:
    wr = csv.writer(f,delimiter="\n")
    wr.writerow(l)
```

Output:

```
hello
how
are
you
```

If you want a trailing comma:

```
with open("out.csv","w") as f:
    wr = csv.writer(f,delimiter="\n")
    for ele in l:
        wr.writerow([ele+","])
```

Output:

```
hello,
how,
are,
you,
```

I would recommend just writing the elements without the trailing comma, there is no advantage to having a trailing comma but may well cause you problems later.

Comment: If you want a trailing comma, wouldn't it work to set the delimiter to `delimiter=',\n'` and then you don't need the extra for loop?

Answer (score 2):

You can just pass this as the value of a dict with key 'column' to a DataFrame constructor and then call `to_csv` on the df:

```
In [43]:

df = pd.DataFrame({'column':['hello','how','are','you']})
df
Out[43]:
  column
0  hello
1    how
2    are
3    you
In [44]:

df.to_csv()
Out[44]:
',column\n0,hello\n1,how\n2,are\n3,you\n'
```

Answer (score 0):

## selecting 120 value from the exsiting data

randss = np.random.choice(dsmodx.logss, 120, replace=False) # 120 Means 120 value
print(randss)

## creating new data frame with selected 120 data from dsmodx.logss data set

randssdf = pd.DataFrame(randss, columns=["Log Ss"])
Saving the data as excel
randssdf.to_excel ('randomSs.xlsx' , index = False)