# writing a list as csv in Python

Tags: python, list, csv

I have a list in Phyton similar to:

```
mylist ='thank you i love you ', 'my mom my biggest supporter’,’ my life line my best friend was a single parent worked 2 jobs to support us im so blessed to have her ’,’ as a mom and now shes my babys nonna happy mothers day mommy i love you', 'me and my mom love her to pieces'.
```

I want to save a csv or txt file whose output should look like:

```
1. thank you  i love you
2. my mom my biggest supporter
3. my life line my best friend was a single parent worked 2 jobs to support us im so blessed to have her
4. as a mom and now shes my babys nonna happy mothers day mommy i love you
5. me and my mom love her to pieces
```

I’ve been trying with:

```
for item in mylist:
    mylist.write("%s/n" % item)
```

But I get:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'write'
```

How shoul I proceed?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can usethe pandas module:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29310792/how-to-save-a-list-as-a-csv-file-with-python-with-new-lines

Comment: also note that csv stands for comma-separated values, which is not really what you present as desired output.

Comment: She'll marry you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That may seem a trivial one, but I didn't find any duplicates answering that particular simple question (looked for them for several minutes!) so here's my proposal:

```
with open("output.txt","w") as f:
    for i,item in enumerate(mylist,1):
        f.write("{}. {}\n".format(i,item))
```

- `mylist` is an input, you cannot `write` into it. You have to open a file object and iterate on `mylist` elements (using `enumerate` to zip it with the indexes starting at 1).
- also you wrote `/n` for linefeed character, which should be `\n` (stay away from `os.linesep` as it would add `\r` twice on Windows)

Comment: Thanks a lot.  It was perfect.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to change the list slightly as sometimes you are using `’` instead the `'`. 
This is the corrected list:

```
myList = 'thank you i love you ', 'my mom my biggest supporter', ' my life line my best friend was a single parent worked 2 jobs to support us im so blessed to have her ', ' as a mom and now shes my babys nonna happy mothers day mommy i love you', 'me and my mom love her to pieces'
```

Secondly, you need to be writing the values to a file object, not a list object.

```
file_object = open('the_output_file_name.txt', 'w')    #creates a file

for item in myList:
    file_object.write("%s\n" % item)    #writes the item to the file

file_object.close()
```

If you want the output to have line numbers like in your example, you could use this which iterates over the list and over a list of numbers equal to the length of the list:

```
file_object = open('the_output_file_name.txt', 'w')    #creates a file

for item, number in zip(myList, range(len(myList))):    #loop over myList and a range()
    file_object.write("%d. %s\n" % (number + 1, item))    #writes the item to the file

file_object.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

mylist is a list object, which do not have write function.
Therefore you got an AttributeError.

You need to open a file to write some data, and here's my solution:

```
with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    [f.write("%d. %s\n" % (i,v)) for i,v in enumerate(mylist, 1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should **write** to a `file` **not to** a `list` object, also, the **single quotes are wrong**, try the following:

```
open('text.txt', 'a').write("\n".join(mylist))
```